# How to add additional references(which are not journals/papers) to the bibtex exported from Mendeley?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies, lyx

I have created a folder which contains a list of scientific journals/papers in Mendeley and then exported the list to .bib file

But there is no provision to add something like datasheet or website or other references to this list?

Comment: You can  the `.bib` file in your editor and add the entries by yourself. This can be done with `jabref` too with its GUI facility.

Comment: @HarishKumar - Thanks for the suggestion. I have explored that option. Wanted to find out if there is any other to do the same via mendeley itself.

Comment: I do not know lyx. You can use an simple editor, for example notepad++, and create a file `mybibfile.bib`. Then you can add there the bibliographical data for your documents. With `\bibliography{menderley,mybibfile}` you can call with pdflatex both bibliography files to be used for your bibliography.

Comment: `.bib` files are just plain text documents, like `.tex` files and `.sty` files and all the rest of it. So you can edit them in any text editor which handles plain text properly. But it is easier if you use an editor which supports syntax highlighting, if you need to do a lot of work in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add entries to Mendeley manually by `File > Add Entry Manually`.

This opens a pop-up, where you can choose the entry type (e.g. `Web Page`, `Generic`, `Bill`, `Journal Article`, etc.).

Once you have typed in what information you want, click `Save`. The entry will now figure as any other Mendeley entry, and will also be present in your generated `.bib` file.

**Do note that the categories of Mendeley do not correspond one-to-one with those of bibtex.** I don't think there is a bibtex type for `Bill`, for example, and I do not know how Mendeley will export that. For that, you'll have to experiment.